# Nothing is showing on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide

My Eclipse IDE has all of a sudden turned blank. I opened it after a couple of days and I see the screen totally blank. I tried to open View -> Package Explorer/Project Explorer but nothing shows up.
My screen looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try to import projects from workspace again. Is it also disabled?

Comment: No perspectives are opened. Try to open any perspective by clicking on the "open perspective button" which was shown after the quick access text box

Comment: I switched to a different workspace so atleast can see the normal view ofcourse without my project. I am not sure what's wrong with my previous workspace that I have been working in and how do I get it back to normal view.

Answer (score 2):

window new window then close the old one.  Had Same issue.  Extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Select `Window` - `New window` or chose at end which you want to open.